# Manipulation linear systems of equations

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I have the following system of equations:

```
i1 = ix - β*ib;
i2 = (β + 1)*ib;
i3 = ix + ib;
vx = i1*Rc + i3*Rb;
v1 = i2*Rϵ + i3*Rb;
v1 = -ib*rπ;
```

I tried using:

```
Solve[i1 == i3 - ib - ib β && i2 == ib (1 + β) && 
      ix == i3 - ib && v1 == -ib rπ && 
      vx == i3 Rb + i3 Rc - ib Rc - ib Rc β && 
      ib Rϵ (1 + β) == -i3 Rb - ib rπ, {vx}]
```

but it gave me no result.

I would like to eliminate the variable v1 and solve for vx/ix in terms of the other variables. I've tried everything I could but I just couldn't get it to work. Would someone please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `Reduce[ ]`instead?

Comment: How exactly should I apply it on the system of equations. I am new to Mathematica.

Comment: You wrote that `Solve[ ]`yourself :) .Replace `Solve` with `Reduce`

Comment: I attempted to apply reduce and eliminated v1. However, when I apply solve, it gives a null answer. QQ

Answer (score 5):

```
eqns = {
   i1 == ix - β*ib,
   i2 == (β + 1)*ib,
   i3 == ix + ib,
   vx == i1*Rc + i3*Rb,
   v1 == i2*Rϵ + i3*Rb,
   v1 == -ib*rπ};

vars = Cases[eqns, _Symbol, Infinity] // Union

(*  {i1, i2, i3, ib, ix, Rb, Rc, Rϵ, rπ, v1, vx, β}  *)

Length /@ {vars, eqns}

(*  {12, 6}  *)
```

With six equations you can pick any six variables to be eliminated. This will leave one equation in the six remaining variables.

```
eqn = Eliminate[eqns, {v1, i1, i2, i3, Rϵ, rπ}]

(*  ib Rb + ix Rb + ix Rc - ib Rc β == vx  *)
```

Or rearranging,

```
FullSimplify /@ (#/ix & /@ eqn)

(*  Rc + ((ib + ix) Rb - ib Rc β)/ix == vx/ix  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
eqn = ReleaseHold[Hold[i1 = ix - β*ib;
      i2 = (β + 1)*ib;
      i3 = ix + ib;
      vx = i1*Rc + i3*Rb;
      v1 = i2*Rϵ + i3*Rb;
      v1 = -ib*rπ] /. Set -> Equal /. CompoundExpression -> List]

var = Complement[Cases[eqn, _Symbol, Infinity] // DeleteDuplicates, {v1}]

ans = {ToRules@Reduce[Eliminate[eqn, v1], var]}
vx/ix /. ans
```

To understand why your attempt failed, try the following code sample:

```
Solve[{a == 1, b == 2}, a]
Solve[{a == 1, b == 2}, {a, b}]
Solve[{a == 1, b == 2}, a, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

Comment: Your solution gives the warning info like `Power::infy: ` and `Infinity::indet` in V8.

Comment: @ShutaoTANG Also in v9, it's just because for one of the possible solutions `vx/ix` is `0/0`.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for the transistor-circuit with the variables beta and the resistors Rb, Rc, rPi and Re, in other words, `Transferfunction vx / ix`, expressed with these variables.

I believe this is your solution:

```
i1 = ix - β ib;
i2 = (β + 1) ib;
i3 = ix + ib;
eq1 = vx == i1*Rc + i3*Rb;
eq2 = -ib*rπ == i2*Rϵ + i3*Rb;

h = vx/ix /. Solve[{eq1, eq2}, {vx, ix}] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @guest, welcome to the site. I've merged your two answers. You will have a better experience if you register your account.